# Why do I never see new items under "Reputation", "Responses", etc.?

Tags: bug, user-interface

On Stack Overflow, I always see a nice update counter for my "Reputation", "Responses", etc. when I click on my nickname at the top. Example:

[image: stackoverflow]

However, this is seemingly not happening on other Stack Exchange sites, including tex.stackexchange.com.

Sure, I can see my reputation, responses, etc. by clicking on those links. However, there is no automatic "new items" counter besides these links, as occurs on Stack Overflow.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see something similar if you hover the mouse over your name. For example, I see
[image]

---

Following the edit: On StackExchange 2.0 sites (like here) things work differently to 1.0 sites like StackOverflow. Reputation appears by your name and updates automatically (some HTML5 magic, I assume). Responses, new badges and so on are handled by the 'universal inbox', which shows up red if you have for example a comment and a sort-of light blue for new badges or edits to your work.

Comment: Yes this works. But what about badges to the left the links, on one's "user" page, as shown in the image I just posted in my original question? Is that a StackOverflow-only feature?